# Nesting shell xtrace

Tags: shell

I have two shell scripts:

```
$ cat a
#!/bin/sh
set -o xtrace
./b

$ cat b
#!/bin/sh
set -o xtrace
echo Oook.

$ ./a
+ ./b
+ echo Oook.
Oook.
```

Is it possible to set shell to nest xtrace outputs from separate scripts? I'd like to see:

```
$ ./a
+ ./b
++ echo Oook.
Oook.
```

Note that it is possible to see nested xtrace output in subshell in the same script:

```
$ cat c
#!/bin/sh
set -o xtrace
echo $(yes | head -c1)

$ ./c
++ yes
++ head -c1
+ echo y
y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible with an unmodified `a` script. But if you are able/willing to modify script invocations, it can be done by sourcing the appropriate script. Viz.:

```
$ cat a
#!/bin/sh
set -o xtrace
. ./b               # Note: sourcing ./b
$ ./a
+ . ./b
++ set -o xtrace
++ echo Oook.
Oook.
$
```

Comment: I can change the `a` script, however it outputs another `+ set -o xtrace` line. I do not want to move `-o xtrace` in the hashbang line, because it is possible to ignore arguments by running the interpreter directly `sh ./a`

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to live with an extra `set -o xtrace`. After all, it *is* a command, and you requested to trace commands. You can easily filter the output if you really need to.